# How to free memory that is allocated in a function but address is returned by that function?

Tags: c, memory-management

I want to know how to free the memory I've dynamically allocated. I know that the memory will get automatically freed after program termination, but what if this function was used as part of a daemon. I believe I would have a memory leak, no?

Here is the code. It is a simple string reverse function.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *my_string_rev(char *string)
{
    // allocate memory to return the new string
    char *out = malloc (sizeof (char));

    assert(out);


    // do things here 
    // ..
    // ..

    return out;
}

int main()
{

   char *str = my_string_rev("true");

   free(str);

   return 0;
}
```

I've tried calling `free(str)` in main to find out that it won't work. Should I worry about freeing the memory returned by `my_string_rev`?

The above calling of `my_string_rev` does in fact work. When the string is longer than 4 characters. So when I call the function with "stackoverflow.com a b", I get this error:

> Error in `./main': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x088d2008 ***

Is that because of malloc allocation? Should I be passing the length of the string to malloc?

Comment: Put free(str) before return and your problem is solved.

Comment: @Igor is right, `free(str)` should work fine.  But I suspect your real problem has to do with `malloc(sizeof(char))` which reserves only enough space for a single character, not the whole reversed string.

Comment: Can you elaborate about why " `free` won't work " ?

Comment: You must be doing some bad things in the `// do things here` part of the program (otherwise, `free(str)` should work fine).

Comment: you know what guys, it was my fault . free(str) does work.

Comment: You've got a lot of points relatively to this type of question (in particular, when considering the fact that there's not really any problem).

Comment: Yes, because it is irrelevant

Comment: Wait, no @Tavian Barnes is right.

Comment: malloc(sizeof(string));

Comment: @barak manos there is a problem. It was my mistake explaining it.

Comment: @Igor: no, `malloc(sizeof(string))` would only allocate space for a `char *`.  Better would be to use `strdup()` if what's needed is a working copy of the string.

Comment: Is it clear what the real question is now? using free when the string passed `my_string_rev` is longer than 4 chars leads to the error.

Comment: @barak manos I understand how you would feel that way. `C` wasn't my first language.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it after writing down that comment above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *out = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
```

`+ 1` because `strlen` does not count `'\0'` character.